# Integral dependence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field. Then $K[X^2]$ in contained in $K[X]$, and it is a finite ring extension. Now let $P(X)$ be a polynomial of $K[X]$. What is the polynomial that $P(X)$ satisfies over $K[X^2]$? Can the integral dependence relation be found out explicitely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $P = Q + XR$ where $Q, R \in K[X^2]$. Then $(P - Q)^2 = X^2 R^2$ is an integral dependence relation for $P$ over $K[X^2]$.

Comment: Expand the relation given and you obtain a quadratic polynomial in $P$ with coefficients in $K[X^2]$.

Comment: ok. got it. thanks